# CASE STATEMENT FOR GETTING COUNT

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the number of accounts completed vs accounts start for each month in a year.

Column `eventlabel` from my table provides the information of start and completed, so want to use that and count how many start and how many completed in that month.

I want to count how many eventlabel are "start" for that particular month, and how many eventlabel are "completed" for that month, and give the count value in a new column renamed as below.

I want the result in the below manner:

```
month year acc_start acc_completed
----------------------------------
09    2021  10         9
11    2021  40         30
12    2021  20         15
```

This is the query I used, but it's unsuccessful:

```
SELECT
    month, year,
    CASE 
        WHEN eventLabel = 'new registration - completed' 
            THEN COUNT(*) AS acc_completed
        WHEN eventLabel = 'new registration - start' 
            THEN COUNT(*) AS acc_start 
    END 
FROM
    tbl_hits
GROUP BY  
    snapshot_month, snapshot_year
```

Pls help.

Comment: Use so called conditional sum - `sum(case when xxxxx then 1 else 0 end) as acc_completed` and so on.

Comment: I dont want to sum up the values, i just need the count of how many start evenlabel, and how many completed eventlabel are present for each month, and then put them into a new column as shown

Comment: It's a case _expression_ not a (stand alone) statement.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd expect a GROUP BY error here - or have you just mixed up the mony and year column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select month,year,
   count(CASE WHEN eventLabel='new registration - completed' 
              THEN 1 END) as acc_completed,
   count(WHEN eventLabel='new registration - start'
              THEN 1 END) as acc_start 
from tbl_hits
group by snapshot_month,snapshot_year
```

Everything outside the aggregate functions (COUNT, in this case) must be in the GROUP BY, so we move the check inside the COUNT. If the condition is not satisfied the result of CASE WHEN is NULL and the COUNT will ignore.

Comment: Sum option `sum(case when xxxxx then 1 else 0 end) as acc_completed` Arvo offered will also work, because it will sum one (1) for each row satisfying the criteria; this is the same as counting.

Comment: This worked perfectly per my need, Thank you